# Resource is not available in the location westeurope - Azure Container Instances with Windows OS

Tags: windows, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-container-instances

I have docker image created by below docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:10.0.17763.1039-amd64

COPY ["processor", "processor/"]

ENTRYPOINT ["processor/Processor.exe"]
```

I'm using Windows as base image because image processing library that we are using requires Windows Media Feature Pack to be installed. When I try to create Azure Container Instances with my result image I'm getting error message:

```
##[error]ServiceUnavailable: The requested resource is not available in the location 'westeurope' at this moment. Please retry with a different resource request or in another location. Resource requested: '2' CPU '4' GB memory 'Windows' OS
```

Windows is not supported as base image in ACI?

And if it is not supported, then how to install Windows Media Feature Pack in Windows Server?

Comment: Could you try it with the another region "eastus"?

Comment: We have policy that allows us to use only Europe regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really strange but I found that you cannot use (at the moment) this specific version. But please try this:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/windows:10.0.17763.973-amd64
```

I know that this is an older image, but at least you will be able to host your app in ACI in your region.

Comment: Using older image is fixing this problem. I have used `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:10.0.17763.914`, but i will try use the one that you proposed in a free time.